# Expert Javascript Iteration Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript

I want to iterate the events list but it fails when I use a `for` loop; is there any solution to loop this part of events:

```
- events:  {  
- title: listtask[i].libelle_task, 
- start:  listtask[i].date_task,  
- end: listtask[i].date_end,
- url: listtask[i].url_task, 
- backgroundColor:"#f56954",//red     
- borderColor: "#f56954"//red
-      },


<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript" >
/*<![CDATA[*/
                        var listtask = /*[[${listtask}]]*/[] ; 
                        var i = 0;
                        var lgt = listtask.length;

        $(function() {

            function ini_events(ele) {
                ele.each(function() {

                    var eventObject = {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text())
                    };
                });
            }
            ini_events($('#external-events div.external-event'));

            var date = new Date();

            var d = date.getDate(),
                    m = date.getMonth(),
                    y = date.getFullYear();

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                buttonText: {
                    today: 'Aujourdhui',

                },
                events: [
for(var i=0;i<lgt;i++)  {
{
                        title: listtask[i].libelle_task,
                        start: listtask[i].date_task,
                        end: listtask[i].date_end,
                        url: listtask[i].url_task,
                        backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
                        borderColor: "#f56954" //red

                    },
}
                ],

                editable: false,
                droppable: false,
                drop: function(date, allDay) { 


                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);


                }
            });



            });


        /*]]>*/
    </script>
```

Comment: Please format you code.

Comment: You'd benefit from learning the basics of the language you're using: an expression can't be an element of an array.

Comment: how to do this with push ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the events loop, use an IIFE to evaluate the object.

```
events  : listtask.map(function(ele) {
           return  {
             title: ele.libelle_task,
             start: ele.date_task,
             end: ele.date_end,
             url: ele.url_task,
             backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
             borderColor: "#f56954" //red
          }
        });
```

BTW:

```
  function ini_events(ele) {
                ele.each(function() {

                    var eventObject = {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text())
                    };
                });
            }
```

Inside the `eventObject` this will refer to the `eventObject` instead of the dom.

So use

```
  function ini_events(ele) {

            ele.each(function(el) {

                var eventObject = {
                    title: $.trim($(el).text())
                };
            });
        }
```

or

```
  function ini_events(ele) {
                ele.each(function() {
                    var self = this;
                    var eventObject = {
                        title: $.trim($(self).text())
                    };
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop you could use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)† to transform (i.e. `map`) the input `listtask` list to the `events` array:

```
var listtask = [a, b, c]; // whatever

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  // ...
  events: _.map(listtask, function(task) {
    return {
      title: task.libelle_task,
      start: task.date_task,
      end: task.date_end,
      url: task.url_task,
      backgroundColor: "#f56954", //red
      borderColor: "#f56954" //red
    };
  })
  // ...
});
```

---

† newer browsers implement the `map` function natively.